# Using react-query's infiniteQuery together with other dynamic parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I was trying to build an infinite list for a search page but the infiniteQuery doesn't pass the page number to the getter function, when using the infiniteQuery to query lists that don't have other parameters the function works fine

**this is the code snippet**

```
    const {
    status,
    data: Articles,
    error,
    isLoading,
    isFetchingNextPage,
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
} = useInfiniteQuery(['get-By-Query-Param', q], () => searchPosts({ search: q }),
    {
        getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => lastPage?.current_page < lastPage?.last_page ? lastPage?.current_page + 1 : undefined,
    },
)
```

in the Networks tab of dev tools i notice that the ?page= param isn't even passed to the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whatever you return from `getNextPageParam` will be passed to your QueryFunction as `pageParam` (as part of the QueryFunctionContext object), and you then have to forward it to your api request, like  `searchPosts`:

```
useInfiniteQuery(
  ['get-By-Query-Param', q],
  // ⬇️ this is where you'll get it
  ({ pageParam }) => searchPosts({ search: q }),
  {
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => lastPage?.current_page < lastPage?.last_page ? lastPage?.current_page + 1 : undefined,
  },
)
```